# Vector Calculus second rank tensor transforms as vector

Tags: tensors

If $σ_{ij} (x)$ is a second-rank tensor field, show that $∂σ_{ij}/∂x_j$ transforms as a vector.

I'm stuck on this question. Must we assume that we sum over $j$? And say that our vector has index $i$?
If we let $\sigma_{ij}=R_{ip}R_{jq}\gamma_{pq}$,and suppose $x_j=R_{jl}y_l$, then for fixed $i,j$, we have
that the above expression is $R_{ip}\frac{\partial \gamma_{pq}}{\partial y_q}$ where we sum over $q$. So for fixed $i,j$ we get the sum version on the right hand side... So I cannot see how, if we sum on the left hand side as well we will get what we require?
eg if the indices vary between 1 and 2, then 
$\partial \sigma_{11}/\partial x_1=R_{11}\partial \gamma_{11}/\partial y_1+R_{11}\partial \gamma_{12}/\partial y_2+R_{12}\partial \gamma_{21}/\partial y_1 + R_{12}\partial \gamma_{22}/\partial y_2 $.

$\partial \sigma_{12}/\partial x_2$ gives me the same expression... What am I doing wrong?